# Files limits in folder

Tags: wordpress, file, size, directory, limit

I encountered with small WP problem. I want to limit one folder (images/avatars), that it should not go to upload file biggest than 100KB. How I can limit this folder? Thanks!

Comment: i am afraid no direct solution might be available , you might need to programmatically check it in WP. if file-size is greater than your specified limit... you should drop user request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you have not posted any code or your effort , let assume example this is code to handle your media post! in WP.

```
require_once(ABSPATH . "wp-admin" . '/includes/image.php');
require_once(ABSPATH . "wp-admin" . '/includes/file.php');
require_once(ABSPATH . "wp-admin" . '/includes/media.php');

$attachment_id = media_handle_upload('file-upload', $post->ID);
```

In my form:

`<input type="file" name="file-upload" id="file-upload" /`>

As far as I know, WordPress has nothing built in for this, I would just do:

```
filesize( get_attached_file( $attachment->ID ) );
```

Or create a custom function

```
function getSize($file){
$bytes = filesize($file);
$s = array('b', 'Kb', 'Mb', 'Gb');
$e = floor(log($bytes)/log(1024));
return sprintf('%.2f '.$s[$e], ($bytes/pow(1024, floor($e))));}
```

> Although WP has two of them built into core. size_format() and
>   wp_convert_bytes_to_hr()

to calculate file size and then if size is greater than 100K and uploaded folder is images/avatars... you can drop user request with some error message!